# Google Test C++: Is there a way to read the current console output in a test?

Tags: c++, googletest

Let us assume I have a to be tested class that has the following method:

```
void
MyClass::sayHello()
{
   std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

Now, within my google test I would like to verify that this output has been made. What would be the *lastConsoleOutput* equivalent be as used in my pseudo code below?

```
// Tests if sayHello() outputs Hello
TEST(MyClassTest, sayHello)\
{
  EXPECT_EQ(lastConsoleOutput,"Hello");
}
```

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would avoid redirecting or testing for values in stdout or stderr, since the access to those streams is not threads-safe in a way that output buffer may not be appended and flushed as possibly predicted.

From a testing perspective I would suggest refactoring the method to be stateless and keep the state (a.k.a. std::cout) somewhere else. In your example you start testing behavior of an external API and not the actual modification in your object.

```
class MyClass {

    std::sstream state;

public:

    void print(){ std::cout << state.str(); } // no need to test this method, only external API

    void changeState() {
        state << "Hello" << std::endl; // this should be tested 
    }

}
```

In your testing code you can now easily perform the test using

```
// Tests if sayHello() outputs Hello
TEST(MyClassTest, sayHello)
{
  myClass.changeState();
  EXPECT_STREQ(myClass.state.str().c_str(),"Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I avoid having code like your `sayHello()` method.  I would refactor it to something like:

```
void MyClass::sayHello(std::ostream& out) {
    out << "Hello";
}
```

Then the test method would be like this:

```
TEST(MyClassTest, sayHello) {
  MyClass c;
  std::stringstream strm;
  c.sayHello(strm);
  EXPECT_STREQ("Hello", strm.str.c_str());
}
```

Comment: You can also redirect stdout and examine the output. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/